# Make iPad trust my HTTPS certificate signed by CA that I created and have added to iPad

Tags: ipad, certificate, mobile-safari

Everything is in my LAN. I created a CA certificate using XCA. On Windows and Android, I could install the CA's ".cer" file system-wise. Chrome-based browsers said that the HTTPS certificate that I created and signed with the CA was valid.

Now, I am trying to do the same thing on an iPad. I downloaded the same ".cer" file, and installed it in Settings. In VPN & Device Management, the certificate is marked as "Verified". But when I opened the HTTPS site in Safari, it said "This connection is not private and in the certificate details, it says "Not trusted" and "issued by" my CA. Why is this so?

I searched the web and found [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477), but in Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings, there is nothing below "Enable full trust for root certificates" other than a link that says "Learn more about trusted certificates".

iPadOS 15.7

CA certificate is installed and valid:
[image]

Safari says the HTTPS certificate is not valid:
[image]

There is nothing below "Enable full trust for root certificates":
[image]

On Android/Windows, the same HTTPS certificate is valid:
[image]
[image]

Comment: When you say “Everything is in my LAN” do you mean this network has no connection to the internet to validate a certificate revocation or that you wish to make self signed certificates that don’t pin on an external validation?

Comment: @bmike Of course, the LAN is connected to the Internet. But the HTTPS is an intranet site that has an NAT IP and a domain name that is not valid outside of my LAN. All the devices are connected to the LAN.